# How can I get the keyboard size without getting an error?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a text view that sits at the bottom of my screen, and would like to push it up when users start editing the text view. I know how to push the view upwards, but because of different screen sizes the display isn't always the same. I'd like to get the height of the keyboard so that the text view sits just above it when a user edits. I have a piece of code below, yet when I add the following 3 lines, the app fails to build and gives me an error. Without this piece of code, the app runs perfectly. The error I get is "swift compiler error: expected declaration". These lines go into my keyboardWillShow function.

```
    if let userInfo = sender.userInfo {
        if let keyboardSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
            keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height
        }
```

So the full code looks like this.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);

}

var isShown: Bool = false
var willHide: Bool = false
var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0

func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {

    isShown = true

//The following 3 lines seem to be the problem. Somehow the code stops working when I add them.
    if let userInfo = sender.userInfo {
        if let keyboardSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
            keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height
        }

}

func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {

    willHide = true

}

func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    if isShown == true {

        self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardHeight

    }
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    if willHide == true {

        self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardHeight

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you check replacing UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey  with UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey.

Comment: The  `if let userInfo = sender.userInfo {` has no closing parenthesis `}` .

Comment: I hate to admit it because I look stupid, but @MartinR is right... I just forgot the curly bracket at the end of the user info constant. Thanks to both of you for the help! :)